# Why isn't Capistrano copying my files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, mediatemple

I am currently deploying a Rails application using Capistrano. `Cap deploy:update_code` usually works just fine to copy over application files from the SVN to the rails container, however when I do it now, it copies the folders but they are all empty. Any ideas of why this would happen or how to fix it?

Comment: I just restarted my computer and it seems to work fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your project out on the server manually to see if everything's checked in. Honestly the only time I've ever seen that is when I was either

deploying an old tag

or

forgot to check stuff in

Capistrano's not doing anything fancy - it's just doing svn co or svn export (depending on your settings).

It would help though to see your deploy.rb though. Without that I'm only guessing.